# C++ Critical Section not working

Tags: c++, vector, critical-section

My critical section code does not work!!!
Backgrounder.run IS able to modify MESSAGE_QUEUE g_msgQueue and LockSections destructor hadn't been called yet !!!

Extra code :

```
typedef std::vector<int> MESSAGE_LIST; // SHARED OBJECT .. MUST LOCK!

class MESSAGE_QUEUE : MESSAGE_LIST{
public:
    MESSAGE_LIST * m_pList;
    MESSAGE_QUEUE(MESSAGE_LIST* pList){ m_pList = pList; }
    ~MESSAGE_QUEUE(){ }
    /* This class will be shared between threads that means any 
     * attempt to access it MUST be inside a critical section. 
     */
    void Add( int messageCode ){ if(m_pList) m_pList->push_back(messageCode); }

    int getLast()
    { 
      if(m_pList){ 
        if(m_pList->size() == 1){ 
          Add(0x0); 
        } 
        m_pList->pop_back(); 
        return m_pList->back(); 
      } 
    }
    void removeLast()
    { 
      if(m_pList){ 
        m_pList->erase(m_pList->end()-1,m_pList->end()); 
      } 
    }
};

class Backgrounder{
public:
    MESSAGE_QUEUE* m_pMsgQueue;
    static void __cdecl Run( void* args){
        MESSAGE_QUEUE* s_pMsgQueue = (MESSAGE_QUEUE*)args;
        if(s_pMsgQueue->getLast() == 0x45)printf("It's a success!");
        else printf("It's a trap!");
    }
    Backgrounder(MESSAGE_QUEUE* pMsgQueue) 
    { 
      m_pMsgQueue = pMsgQueue; 
      _beginthread(Run,0,(void*)m_pMsgQueue); 
    }
    ~Backgrounder(){ }
};

int main(){

    MESSAGE_LIST g_List;
    CriticalSection crt;
    ErrorHandler err;
    LockSection lc(&crt,&err); // Does not work , see question #2
    MESSAGE_QUEUE g_msgQueue(&g_List);
    g_msgQueue.Add(0x45); 
    printf("%d",g_msgQueue.getLast()); 
    Backgrounder back_thread(&g_msgQueue);


    while(!kbhit());
    return 0;
}

#ifndef CRITICALSECTION_H
#define CRITICALSECTION_H
#include <windows.h>
#include "ErrorHandler.h"


class CriticalSection{
    long m_nLockCount;
    long m_nThreadId;
    typedef CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    cs m_tCS;
public:
    CriticalSection(){
        ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_tCS);
        m_nLockCount = 0;
        m_nThreadId = 0;
    }
    ~CriticalSection(){ ::DeleteCriticalSection(&m_tCS); }
    void Enter(){ ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_tCS);  }
    void Leave(){  ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_tCS); }
    void Try();
};


class LockSection{
    CriticalSection* m_pCS;
    ErrorHandler * m_pErrorHandler;
    bool m_bIsClosed;
public:
    LockSection(CriticalSection* pCS,ErrorHandler* pErrorHandler){
        m_bIsClosed = false;
        m_pCS = pCS;
        m_pErrorHandler = pErrorHandler;
            // 0x1AE is code prefix for critical section header
        if(!m_pCS)m_pErrorHandler->Add(0x1AE1); 
        if(m_pCS)m_pCS->Enter();
    }
    ~LockSection(){
        if(!m_pCS)m_pErrorHandler->Add(0x1AE2);
        if(m_pCS && m_bIsClosed == false)m_pCS->Leave();
    }
    void ForceCSectionClose(){
        if(!m_pCS)m_pErrorHandler->Add(0x1AE3);
        if(m_pCS){m_pCS->Leave();m_bIsClosed = true;}
    }
};

/*

Safe class basic structure;

class SafeObj
{
     CriticalSection m_cs;

public:
    void SafeMethod()
    {
        LockSection myLock(&m_cs);
        //add code to implement the method ...

    }
};



*/
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two questions in one. I don't know about the first, but the critical section part is easy to explain. The background thread isn't trying to claim the lock and so, of course, is not blocked. You need to make the critical section object `crt` visible to the thread so that it can lock it.

The way to use this lock class is that each section of code that you want serialised must create a `LockSection` object and hold on to it until the end of the serialised block:

**Thread 1:**

```
{
    LockSection lc(&crt,&err);
    //operate on shared object from thread 1
}
```

**Thread 2:**

```
{
    LockSection lc(&crt,&err);
    //operate on shared object from thread 2
}
```

Note that it has to be the same critical section instance `crt` that is used in each block of code that is to be serialised.

Comment: Thanks david. I modified the post so it's one question now, the most important one. I guess that means I have to use LockSection in Backgrounder::run too !

Comment: I have this code now : if (void*)args is 2 pointers , how do you extract each one of them? example _beginthread(Run,0,(void*)(m_pMsgQueue,m_pLc)); ... static void __cdecl Run( void* args){ p1 = arg1; p2 = arg2; } ?

Comment: That's a different question. Can't really address it easily in comments. Feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

This code has a number of problems.

First of all, deriving from the standard containers is almost always a poor idea. In this case you're using private inheritance, which reduces the problems, but doesn't eliminate them entirely. In any case, you don't seem to put the inheritance to much (any?) use anyway. Even though you've derived your `MESSAGE_QUEUE` from `MESSAGE_LIST` (which is actually `std::vector<int>`), you embed a pointer to an instance of a `MESSAGE_LIST` into `MESSAGE_QUEUE` anyway.

Second, if you're going to use a queue to communicate between threads (which I think *is* generally a good idea) you should make the locking inherent in the queue operations rather than requiring each thread to manage the locking correctly on its own.

Third, a `vector` isn't a particularly suitable data structure for representing a queue anyway, unless you're going to make it fixed size, and use it roughly like a ring buffer. That's not a bad idea either, but it's quite a bit different from what you've done. If you're going to make the size dynamic, you'd probably be better off starting with a deque instead.

Fourth, the magic numbers in your error handling (0x1AE1, 0x1AE2, etc.) is quite opaque. At the very least, you *need* to give these meaningful names. The one comment you have does *not* make the use anywhere close to clear.

Finally, if you're going to go to all the trouble of writing code for a thread-safe queue, you might as well make it generic so it can hold essentially any kind of data you want, instead of dedicating it to one specific type.

Ultimately, your code doesn't seem to save the client much work or trouble over using the Windows functions directly. For the most part, you've just provided the same capabilities under slightly different names.

IMO, a thread-safe queue should handle almost all the work internally, so that client code can use it about like it would any other queue.

```
// Warning: untested code.
// Assumes: `T::T(T const &) throw()` 
//
template <class T>
class queue { 
    std::deque<T> data;
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    HANDLE semaphore;
public:
    queue() { 
        InitializeCriticalSection(&cs); 
        semaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 2048, NULL);
    }

    ~queue() { 
        DeleteCriticalSection(&cs); 
        CloseHandle(semaphore);
    }

    void push(T const &item) {         
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
        data.push_back(item);
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
        ReleaseSemaphore(semaphore, 1, NULL);
    }

    T pop() { 
        WaitForSingleObject(semaphore, INFINITE);
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
        T item = data.front();
        data.pop_front();
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
        return item;
    }
};



HANDLE done;

typedef queue<int> msgQ;

enum commands { quit, print };

void backgrounder(void *qq) { 

  // I haven't quite puzzled out what your background thread
  // was supposed to do, so I've kept it really simple, executing only
  // the two commands listed above.
  msgQ *q = (msgQ *)qq;
  int command;

  while (quit != (command = q->pop()))
      printf("Print\n");
  SetEvent(done);
}

int main() { 
    msgQ q;
    done = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);
    _beginthread(backgrounder, 0, (void*)&q);
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
        q.push(print);
    q.push(quit);
    WaitForSingleObject(done, INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 - that's twice this year that I've been forced agree with a Lounger and upvote :(

Answer (score 2):

Your background thread needs access to the same `CriticalSection` object and it needs to create `LockSection` objects to lock it -- the locking is collaborative.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return the last element *after* popping it.